# How to disable SSLv2 or SSLv3?

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5

Anyone know how to disable certain SSL versions and only enable others in IIS 7.5?

Comment: Disabling SSL 2.0 sounds like a really bad idea; are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: @blueberryfields: SSLv2 is *ancient*, current version is TLSv1.1 (TLSv1=SSLv3), and has known security holes

Comment: Disabling SSL 2.0 is a very good idea (and required to pass a PCI compliance test).

Comment: If you need the updated KB from MS, try this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245030 It's the one that IIS Crypto uses...

Answer (score 24):

1. Open `regedit`
2. Navigate to, or create the keys as necessary:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server
   ```
3. Create/Edit the value `Enabled`, type DWORD, value "0"
4. Reboot

Notes: The same proceedure applied to key names `PCT 1.0`, `SSL 2.0`, `SSL 3.0`, `TLS 1.0`. In newer versions of Windows some of these are disabled by default - which depends on what version.

Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187498

Answer (score 8):

This is something you need to fix in regedit,

regedit can be opened with "start", "run", `regedit`

once there, find this entry:

`HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0`

Right-click on the SSL 2.0 folder and select New and then click Key. Name the new folder Server.

Inside the Server folder, click the Edit menu, select New, and click DWORD (32-bit) Value.

Enter Enabled as the name and hit Enter.

Ensure that it shows `0x00000000` (0) under the Data column (it should by default). If it doesn't, right-click and select Modify and enter 0 as the Value data.

Restart the computer.

a nice explanation can be found here, including how to disable other weak ciphers

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-disable-ssl-2.0-in-iis-7.html

Comment: and now, I guess we have to start disabling SSLv3.0 also

Answer (score 6):

If you are not comfortable manually editing the registry, you can either use a power shell script or a GUI program to do all this for you.

There is a great script by Alexnder Hass [here - Setup your IIS for SSL Perfect Forward Secrecy and TLS 1.2](https://www.hass.de/content/setup-your-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12)

I personally like to use [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) it is so easy and lets you order and choose crypto suites, ciphers etc. You can just use the 'best practices' if you are not sure what you are doing.

[image]

Also, once you are done rebooting the server, head over to [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to test your server.

Good Luck!

Comment: Really nice App.